# Readable Angular.js Errors?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular.js does not provide human-readable error messages by default.

Is there anyway to change the default, cryptic Angular.js exception URL to a more readable error message? As it is, I have to copy the URL, remove the prefix, and paste in the browser to see what the problem is.

For example, transforming the following exception to a more useful error message:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/ng/areq?p0=InterfaceController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined y/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular....
```

To something like:

```
"Missing required argument to InterfaceController"
```

I know I can provide my own exception handler:

```
.factory('$exceptionHandler', function () {
  return function errorCatcherHandler(exception, cause) {
    console.error(exception);
  };
});
```

Am I approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was that I was developing against the minified/compressed version (assuming it was like other JS libraries). The *uncompressed* version includes a readable error message.

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! xD

Comment: saved me from hours!!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have readable error in your console, use **non-minified version** of angular libraries

--

To know what your current error is : copy those link and paste them in browser it will take you to the page where you can read more details about that particular error.

I pasted your error in browser url and i got

```
 Error: error:areq Bad Argument
 Argument 'InterfaceController' is not a function, got undefined
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I said I was doing. I wanted to stop that though since it's a waste of time for most simple errors.